# why my ajax success data is not display in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to call ajax and get my HTML contend .But I want to show that data on tooltip/or pop over .I am getting the data on console I don't know why it showing black data tooltip it is showing black .is there problem in binding ?

here is plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/OYiawflIBnpJ1PKx02LG?p=preview
when you click "star" image it show blank data.why ?
[image]

```
app.directive('mypopover', function ($compile,$templateCache) {
    var getTemplate = function (contentType,scope,element) {

        var template = $templateCache.get("templateId.html");

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'partials/popup.html',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                alert('d'+data)
                var options = {
                    content: $(template).html(data),
                    placement: "right",
                    html: true,
                    date: scope.date
                };
                $(element).popover(options);
            },
            error: function (data) {


            }
        });

        return template;
    }
    return {
        restrict: "A",

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('entering link')
            var popOverContent;
            popOverContent = getTemplate("user",scope,element);


        }
    };
});
```

Comment: put a console.log() or alert() in your error callback

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/OYiawflIBnpJ1PKx02LG?p=preview.added a alert in error

Comment: This seems to work http://plnkr.co/edit/2cNYagz12oK5NMBOZtj6?p=preview but it's returning an object.  Not sure what your template setup is. But this works http://plnkr.co/edit/4qwF0KgxkRk4FGmrTgDN?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was few error please see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/5SpDRkMokbPCMRT8oB0r?p=preview

```
app.directive('mypopover', function($compile, $templateCache) {
  var getTemplate = function(contentType, scope, element) {

    var template = $templateCache.get("templateId.html");

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'pop.html',
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log($(template).html(data));
        var options = {


          content: data,
          placement: "right",
          html: true,
          date: scope.date
        };
        $(element).popover(options);
      },
      error: function(data) {
        alert(data)

      }
    });

    return template;
  }
  return {
    restrict: "A",

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log('entering link')
      var popOverContent;
      popOverContent = getTemplate("user", scope, element);


    }
  };
});
```

html:

```
<head>

    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.1" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@1.2.16" data-semver="1.2.16" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/a98aey2mlu0h511/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src=" https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/s1imyubboz1qjtl/bootstrap-popover.js?m="></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
```

Comment: I am getting pop over on movesover ? can we get this on  "click" on star icon ?

Comment: @user3665790   yes please see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/lH9r6wXLVvdcKSiactLC?p=preview

Comment: @thanks for ansering but there is problem in that code..example when you click on first star icon it open the pop over .if you click again than open the pop over without closing first

Comment: @sywester can we do that only one popover open atone time

Comment: @user3665790 I will try tomorrow is bed time for me, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

The error was in your `<script>` tags list : http://plnkr.co/edit/GUlSHxy6aEwfVZuXFwDM?p=preview

```
        <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/a98aey2mlu0h511/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>

    <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/s1imyubboz1qjtl/bootstrap-popover.js?m="></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```